# Fabric fails with Name lookup failed when celery is run with eventlet

Tags: python, celery, fabric, openstack, eventlet

I have a celery task to run a sudo command on a remote machine using fabric:

```
@app.task(soft_time_limit=600)
def run_puppet_agent(hostname):
    try:
        fabric_client = Fabric(hostname)
        result = fabric_client.run_command('puppet agent -t', True, True)
        if result.return_code == 0 or result.return_code == 2:
                return True, 'Puppet agent run successfully'
        else:
            raise Exception('Command %s run failed with a non zero or non-2 error code, '
                            '0 and 2 are status codes for successful puppet runs, returned     code %s'
                            % ('sudo puppet agent -t', result.return_code))
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        raise Exception('Puppet agent run took more than 600 seconds')
    except Exception as e:
        #run_puppet_agent.retry(args=[hostname], countdown=20)
        LOG.info('')
        raise Exception('Puppet agent failed with error message %s' % e.message)
```

if I run the celery workers as:

```
celery -A phantom.celery.manage worker --loglevel=info
```

it works fine !! But when I run the workers with eventlet as:

```
celery -A phantom.celery.manage worker --loglevel=info -P eventlet -c 15
```

It goes terribly bad and gives me this exception:

```
[WARNING/MainProcess] File     "/Users/uruddarraju/Phantom/phantom/tasks/fabric_tasks.py", line 19, in run_puppet_agent
[WARNING/MainProcess] result = fabric_client.run_command('puppet agent -t', True, True)
[WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Users/uruddarraju/Phantom/phantom/util/fabric/fabric_util.py", line 43, in run_command
[WARNING/MainProcess] return sudo(command, quiet=False)
[WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 639, in host_prompting_wrapper
[WARNING/MainProcess] return func(*args, **kwargs)
[WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 1095, in sudo
[stderr=stderr, timeout=timeout, shell_escape=shell_escape,
[WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/operations.py", line 909, in _run_command
[WARNING/MainProcess] channel=default_channel(), command=wrapped_command, pty=pty,
[WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/state.py", line 390, in default_channel
[WARNING/MainProcess] chan = _open_session()
[WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/state.py", line 382, in _open_session
[WARNING/MainProcess] return connections[env.host_string].get_transport().open_session()
[WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 151, in __getitem__
[WARNING/MainProcess] self.connect(key)
[WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 143, in connect
[WARNING/MainProcess] self[key] = connect(user, host, port, cache=self)
[WARNING/MainProcess] File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/fabric/network.py", line 533, in connect
[WARNING/MainProcess] raise NetworkError('Name lookup failed for %s' % host, e)
[WARNING/MainProcess] NetworkError: Name lookup failed for <hostname>
```

WARNING/MainProcess] None

FYI: I have other tasks that have different HTTP API calls and hence though eventlet would help but not working for me in this case

Comment: what's the result of running `hostname` on that computer? (and is that in `/etc/hosts`)?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry, I can't give the hostname.

Comment: doesn't really matter what hostname is, so long as it's in the file.

Comment: Please, post output of: `import eventlet; eventlet.connect((hostname, 22))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used gevent instead to work...solved my problem !! Thanks for the help though